# How can I use the Swagger UI open openapi document?

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-3.1

I check out the latest code from Swagger UI 3.25.0 on github and add some features like saving and loading requet data. It works fine with Swagger 2.0 doc which has a json file like this

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "version":"1.0",
      "title":"Order api",
      "description":"Order api"
   },
   "paths":{
      "/api/v1/internal/orderdispatch/DispatchOrder/DispatchOrdersByIdList":{
         "post":{
            "tags":[
               "Myaz.OrderDispatch.API.Controllers/DispatchOrder"
            ],
            "operationId":"POST_api_v1_internal_orderdispatch_DispatchOrder_DispatchOrdersByIdList",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json-patch+json",
               "application/json",
               "text/json",
               "application/*+json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "name":"salesOrderIdList",
                  "in":"body",
                  "required":false,
                  "schema":{
                     "uniqueItems":false,
                     "type":"array",
                     "items":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"Success"
               }
            },
            "deprecated":false
         }
      },
   }
}
```

But it seems that it can't open the OAS 3.0 doc which has the following structure.

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "My API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/OrderRouter/SalesOrder/CreateSalesOrder": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "SalesOrder"
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Myaz.ERP.Model.OrderRouter.ViewModel.SalesOrderViewModel"
              }
            },
            "text/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Myaz.ERP.Model.OrderRouter.ViewModel.SalesOrderViewModel"
              }
            },
            "application/*+json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Myaz.ERP.Model.OrderRouter.ViewModel.SalesOrderViewModel"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Currently I'm using asp.net core 3.1 which only support OAS doc. So how can I use swagger UI to show OAS 3.0 doc?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swagger UI supports both OAS2 and OAS3. What do you mean by "it can't open the OAS 3.0 doc"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's a cors issue. You are right.